# When to use "Ok noted"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences

I'm a software developer. My situation is, I'm working with my customer (onshore project manager) via chatting using Skype.
He helps me to make his side's server available and give me a link to the test page so that I can test the page.
After he send me the link. I reply:

```
OK.
I will test it now.
```

But my boss (solution architect) immediate talk to me (via Skype too)

```
You should say "Ok noted"
```

Could anybody please explain when to use "Ok noted"?
What are differences between "Ok" and "Ok noted"?

Sorry for my English. Thank a lot!

Comment: Maybe your boss is just trying to be important?

Comment: I think your boss wants you to indicate that you've taken notice of something: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+notice+of But also see: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=noted

Comment: The only difference I can see is that you are saying that you will test it *now*, whereas your boss's wording acknowledges that you've received the link, but makes no promise as to when (or whether) it will be tested. So your boss's wording allows you to delay testing if you have other priorities to attend to first.

Comment: @user814064 If so, I can say "I took notice of it" instead of "OK"?

Comment: Saying okay is fine. But it's not worth fighting a boss over so just say ok, noted.

Comment: No! Do not say "I took notice of it." It is not idiomatic English. If that's what you want to say, "Noted." is *far* better.

Comment: Nex time try with "One is glad to be of service" ;-)) (from "Bicentennial Man")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"OK Noted" would be considered a pointless affectation in many environments. It doesn't necessarily add any information, and in most IT environments, your response would give exactly the right amount of information.

That said, he is your boss, so depending on your particular goals and aims, and his personality, you may just wish to go with "OK Noted" anyway.

Comment: While I broadly agree, I would take issue with "exactly the right amount of information" - one of the few viable reasons to say 'noted' would be to provide confirmation of acceptance (I will test that) without giving a timescale. If you say 'I will test that now', it seems more like you are taking instruction on when to do things, rather than taking responsibility for performing the task at a moment of your own choosing.

Answer (score 8):

I hear "OK Noted" in meetings all the time.  It has two very subtle meanings.

#1 - We got what you are saying, let's move on.  (way to shut someone up)

#2 - Jotted that down for meeting notes.  Meaning they said the phrase to communicate to you that they took a note on your idea/conversation/task.   If there is a possible action item for the "OK Noted" conversation you can be sure to see it in an email soon.

Comment: About #2, could you please explain more detail? Thanks!

Comment: @TuanDang - does the edit help?

Comment: yes! thank for more use of "OK Noted"

Comment: It is really about the tone of the person who said it and the context.  These two meanings are pretty far apart from each other.  One means we have had enough of this topic and the other means the topic was important enough to take a note on.

Answer (score 3):

In this situation "OK." would be considered acceptable.

I know a couple people that insist it's an overly curt reply, but most people in our field recognize it for what it is.  It's a simple acknowledgement of receiving data.  It stems from handshake protocols and how every "push" has a reply to acknowledge that it was properly received.

Comment: Why do you say "it stems from the handshake protocols"?

Answer (score 3):

"I will test it now" of course is the better answer. It tells your customers of the next step and every customer wants your next step.

"OK noted" stops the conversation. There is no commitment of action on your part. It is nothing but a recognition that you have received something. Whatever you want to do next, your customer will not know.

When you talk to a customer, put yourself on her or his shoes. Customers are human beings, not just a part of your job or something which is part of the process.

I suggest you continue what you are doing. However, before that, ask your boss if "OK Noted" is a policy or just a matter of style. It it is a policy, get a plain English book and give your boss a copy.